# Check for null values in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am very new to Python, and I wanted to ask a question about how to check the null values as condition in if statement. I am not sure how to construct the syntax. Hopefully someone can help me to solve the problem. Thank you so much, and wish you all have a wonderful day.

So here is problem. I am working with a dataframe, and I want to sort my row first on condition, then do the calculation, the dataframe is look like that:
Column A    Column B
0
1
2
3
4
5
...

I want to calculate the average of Column A and Column B, but if Column A is null, the average will be Column B, and when Column B is null, average will be Column A. The Code that I constructed is following:

```
if df['A'].notnull is True & df['B'].notnull is True:
    df['Avg']=df['A'].astype(float)/2 + df['B'].astype(float)/2
elif df['A'].notnull is True & df['B'].isnull is True:
    df['Avg']=df['A'].astype(float)
else df['A'].isnull is True & df['B'].notnull is True:
    df['Avg']=df['B'].astype(float)
```

My code looks like this. Will someone provide plausible solutions, please? Thank you all.

Comment: Note that `&` is the bitwise AND operator. `and` is logical AND.

Comment: `df['A'].notnull` I believe this is checking the entire column, and therefore the return value won't simply be true or false; it will be an _array_ of true/false values, one per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

E.g., something like:

```
df.loc[df['A'].notnull() & df['B'].notnull(), "Avg"] = (df['A'].astype(float) + df['B'].astype(float))/2
```

And similarly for the other conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried the idea and it is working smoothly. Thank you